# How do I remove a directory that has a file with colon in it

Tags: terminal

I am trying to delete a directory with `rm -rf` however I keep getting the error `Directory not empty`.

If I do an `ls` on the directory I see this message `ls: HTML : CSS: No such file or directory`.

So it sounds like there's a file or directory that has a colon in it. Is there anyway I can delete that file or directory with the colon in it?

Comment: Is your problem fully solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it is on your local drive

```
rm DIRECTORY/*\:*
```

should remove the file.

Answer (score 0):

cd to the directory and type rm, press space, then tab. Autocomplete will fill the command with the folder name using the correct escaping to select the folder. You can then delete the folder by running the command.